# PHP and JS use autocomplete/sql to autofill another text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

So I use some php and js/jquery to autocomplete/autofull one textbox as they type into it. I want it once the first text input is filled for it to look at that value and kick off another sql query to get the data to fill the next text box input. Basicly as they type in the device once it is finished I want it to look for the IP of that device and fill in the next box.

```
    <?php 
// php code that selects data from sql and puts into an array then json encodes array as $jArr
    ?>
```

Javascript code:

```
  <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
          GetLocalityList();      
      });

      function GetLocalityList() {
          var LocalityArray = <?php echo $jArr?>;

          $("#device").autocomplete({
              minLength: 1,
              source: function(req, responseFn) {
                  //  \\b show each match letter in each word of list
                  //  ^ show each match letter in whole word of list
                  var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term), "i");
                  var a = $.grep(LocalityArray, function(item, index) {
                      return matcher.test(item);
                  });
                  responseFn(a);
              }
          });
      }
    </script>
```

html code:

```
<form action="addNewData.php" method="post">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>


        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <label for="device">Device being serviced: &nbsp;</label><br>
                    <input type = "text" name = "device" id="device" value = "">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <div class="ui-widget">
                      <label for="ipaddress">Ip Address: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><br>
                      <input type="text" name="ipaddress" id = "ipaddress" value = "">
                    </div>
                </td>
        </tr>
.....
```

Comment: What does the returned JSON look like?

Comment: just a json array of device names. that part works, I cannot figure out how to get the second text to take the results of the first one and look up the IP.

Comment: Then expand your JSON and add the ip address to each of those machines. Then you probably have to edit the `autocomplete` function you're using to add that ip-address to the second input.

Comment: If you're planning to "kick off another sql query to get the data to fill the next text box input", then you will need to use an Ajax call & a server-side SQL query. The code example is missing the Ajax call. It looks like you're filtering a predefined PHP rendered list, rather than doing real-time searching using Ajax.